# Querying RLMObject with NSPredicate returns no result

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Here's my Realm model:

**Pet.h**

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface Pet : RLMObject

@property NSString *species;

@end
```

**Pet.m**

```
#import "Pet.h"

@implementation Pet

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"species";
}

@end
```

**Write into Realm**

```
- (void)writeCat {
       RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
       [realm beginWriteTransaction];

       Pet *pet = [[Pet alloc] init];
       pet.species = @"cat";//as Primary Key
      [Pet createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:pet];

      [realm commitWriteTransaction];

      for (Pet *pet in [Pet allObjects]) {

          NSLog(@"pet in realm: %@", pet);
          //prints out: 
          //pet in realm: Pet {species = cat;}
      }
}
```

**Query from Realm** (after data gets written)

```
- (void)queryCat {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate 
                              predicateWithFormat: @"species == %@", @"cat"];
      RLMResults *cat = [Pet objectsWithPredicate:predicate];
      RLMResults *all = [Pet allObjects];

      NSLog(@"cat: %@ and all: %@", cat, all);
      //prints out: 
      //cat: RLMResults <0x7fdeed8e8710> ( )
      //and all: RLMResults <0x7ffa151c6630> ( )
}
```

***EDIT***

How I called methods:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{
   [self writeCat];
   [self queryCat];
}
```

I did write something into Realm but query nothing from it,

What did i do wrong about the querying?

Comment: It seems there is no problem in your code. And I'm sure that your code executed successfully in my environment. Could you please show the code where calling `writeCat ` and  `queryCat` methods?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi Just called [self writeCat] and then [self queryCat] without doing anything else. It's weird that `[Pet allObjects]` would success right after `[realm commitWriteTransaction]` but would fail at any other time. While the cat query never success at any time.

Comment: The code you provided does not reproduce the issue for me either. I've put the project I was testing with online at https://github.com/bdash/realm-test-so-32345896 so you can compare your local code with what I tested with. I suspect there's a detail you're omitting that's relevant to the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @bdash you're right! I just found that I left `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration].path error:nil]` right above `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];` It seemed to remove all my data before writing and of course I won't get any older results ... what a time killer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RLMResults *allResults = [Pet allObjects];    //getting all objects
allResults = [allResults objectsWhere:@"species contains 'cat'"]; // querying for cat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  RLMResults *results = [Pet objectsWhere:@"species = 'cat'"];
  if(results.count){
      Pet *foundedPet = results.firstObject;
  }
```